# source code for the alert() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the source code for the default alert() function in Javascript(method of the window object)? I am trying to write an alert function myself so I would really like to get a peek at the original function code.It is so hard to google it.

Comment: `alert()` is a part of JavaScript, it is just standard.  If you'd like to see an example of an open source alert, this might be useful: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

Comment: What is your goal? What do you mean by "source code"? The Browser automatically interprets `alert()`. It's a method of the `window` Object. It's constructor is `Function`.

Answer (score 4):

The `alert()` function, like a number of other standard functions, is a part of the browser's Javascript runtime. It cannot be replicated with Javascript code (other than by calling `alert()`), and there is no platform-independent Javascript source code to the function.

Answer (score 3):

It's a compiled function, probably different for every browser, so there is no source JS code for it.

You've noticed when you call it how it takes over the whole browser - it's not a part of the webpage like a popup or something; so if you're trying to achieve something like that (control at a lower level of the browser), there's no way to do it from JS. If you only need a popup, there are tons of online resources about how it do it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the nature of alert, it helps

Answer (score 0):

The source code for `alert()` is... `alert()`

It is a primitive Word. If you want details, they are yet in another language.
Interpreted directly by the browser.