# javascript if native function deleted How to recover

Tags: javascript, hook

if javascript native function as `alert`

```
alert = null
```

If I want to use `alert` how to recover it

Comment: It's gone. So don't do it.

Comment: nothing is ever gone :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [source code for the alert() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768668/source-code-for-the-alert-function)

Comment: not really a duplicate @user2968356

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably wont work in all browsers

```
var x = document.createElement('iframe');
x.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(x);
window.alert = x.contentWindow.alert.bind(window);
// x.remove();
x.parentElement.removeChild(x); // because IE sux and should die
```

Seems to work most places (Firefox, Chrum, Edge, and IE11)